# DNS not resolving after switch to AWS Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I recently transferred a domain (superteachertools.net) from GoDaddy to AWS.
The domain was running on a dedicated server with GoDaddy in the Plesk environment.  That server is now shut down.

It's been about a week, but the DNS records I've set up at AWS on Route 53 do not seem to be propagating.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to add a lot more details. For this kind of question, it's also usually a very good idea to name the domain in question so we can look at how DNS records look like from our side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same domain name in your `NS` records but you are missing *glue records*.

```
superteachertools.net.  172800  IN      NS      ns2.superteachertools.net.
superteachertools.net.  172800  IN      NS      ns1.superteachertools.net.
dig: couldn't get address for 'ns2.superteachertools.net': no more
```

Your domain is registered at Amazon, you should add them there:

```
Domain Name: superteachertools.net
Registry Domain ID: 1835524431_DOMAIN_NET-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.registrar.amazon.com
Registrar URL: https://registrar.amazon.com
Updated Date: 2017-06-12T02:37:24.255Z
```

See Route 53 documentation, [Adding or Changing Name Servers and Glue Records for a Domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html).

> You can also use this procedure to specify glue records (IP addresses)
>   when you're configuring white label name servers—name servers that
>   have the same domain name as the hosted zone. For more information
>   about configuring white label name servers (also known as vanity name
>   servers or private name servers), see [Configuring White Label Name
>   Servers.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/white-label-name-servers.html)

Probably you have transferred your domain on 2017-06-12 to Amazon and it has just copied your

```
Name Server: ns1.superteachertools.net
Name Server: ns2.superteachertools.net
```

without adding the glue records automatically. Add glue records or change DNS servers as needed on the [Amazon Route 53 console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/) > **Registered Domains** > `superteachertools.net` > **Add/Edit Name Servers** > **Edit Name Servers**.

Comment: I think that was it!  I was looking in the hosted zones and never saw that other page.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your Name Server records at your domain registrar are not pointing to Route53. You'll need to edit your domain records in Amazon Domains so that your name servers are pointing to the four servers indicated in NS records in your R53 zone.

See the output of this whois query for your domain:

```
Whois Server Version 2.0

Domain names in the .com and .net domains can now be registered
with many different competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net
for detailed information.

   Domain Name: SUPERTEACHERTOOLS.NET
   Registrar: AMAZON REGISTRAR, INC.
   Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 468
   Whois Server: whois.registrar.amazon.com
   Referral URL: http://registrar.amazon.com
   Name Server: NS1.SUPERTEACHERTOOLS.NET
   Name Server: NS2.SUPERTEACHERTOOLS.NET
   Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
   Updated Date: 12-jun-2017
   Creation Date: 15-nov-2013
   Expiration Date: 15-nov-2018

>>> Last update of whois database: Thu, 15 Jun 2017 16:28:06 GMT <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp

NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the
registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is
currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration
date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring
registrar.  Users may consult the sponsoring registrar's Whois database to
view the registrar's reported date of expiration for this registration.

TERMS OF USE: You are not authorized to access or query our Whois
database through the use of electronic processes that are high-volume and
automated except as reasonably necessary to register domain names or
modify existing registrations; the Data in VeriSign Global Registry
Services' ("VeriSign") Whois database is provided by VeriSign for
information purposes only, and to assist persons in obtaining information
about or related to a domain name registration record. VeriSign does not
guarantee its accuracy. By submitting a Whois query, you agree to abide
by the following terms of use: You agree that you may use this Data only
for lawful purposes and that under no circumstances will you use this Data
to: (1) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass
unsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations via e-mail, telephone,
or facsimile; or (2) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes
that apply to VeriSign (or its computer systems). The compilation,
repackaging, dissemination or other use of this Data is expressly
prohibited without the prior written consent of VeriSign. You agree not to
use electronic processes that are automated and high-volume to access or
query the Whois database except as reasonably necessary to register
domain names or modify existing registrations. VeriSign reserves the right
to restrict your access to the Whois database in its sole discretion to ensure
operational stability.  VeriSign may restrict or terminate your access to the
Whois database for failure to abide by these terms of use. VeriSign
reserves the right to modify these terms at any time.

The Registry database contains ONLY .COM, .NET, .EDU domains and
Registrars.
Domain Name: superteachertools.net
Registry Domain ID: 1835524431_DOMAIN_NET-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.registrar.amazon.com
Registrar URL: https://registrar.amazon.com
Updated Date: 2017-06-12T02:37:24.255Z
Creation Date: 2013-11-15T02:51:00Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2018-11-15T02:51:00Z
Registrar: Amazon Registrar, Inc.
Registrar IANA ID: 468
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: registrar-abuse@amazon.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.2062661000
Reseller:
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: ok https://icann.org/epp#ok
Registry Registrant ID:
Registrant Name: On behalf of superteachertools.net owner
Registrant Organization: Whois Privacy Service
Registrant Street: P.O. Box 81226
Registrant City: Seattle
Registrant State/Province: WA
Registrant Postal Code: 98108-1226
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: +1.2065771368
Registrant Phone Ext:
Registrant Fax:
Registrant Fax Ext:
Registrant Email: owner-1263595@superteachertools.net.whoisprivacyservice.org
Registry Admin ID:
Admin Name: On behalf of superteachertools.net administrative contact
Admin Organization: Whois Privacy Service
Admin Street: P.O. Box 81226
Admin City: Seattle
Admin State/Province: WA
Admin Postal Code: 98108-1226
Admin Country: US
Admin Phone: +1.2065771368
Admin Phone Ext:
Admin Fax:
Admin Fax Ext:
Admin Email: admin-1263595@superteachertools.net.whoisprivacyservice.org
Registry Tech ID:
Tech Name: On behalf of superteachertools.net technical contact
Tech Organization: Whois Privacy Service
Tech Street: P.O. Box 81226
Tech City: Seattle
Tech State/Province: WA
Tech Postal Code: 98108-1226
Tech Country: US
Tech Phone: +1.2065771368
Tech Phone Ext:
Tech Fax:
Tech Fax Ext:
Tech Email: tech-1263595@superteachertools.net.whoisprivacyservice.org
Name Server: ns1.superteachertools.net
Name Server: ns2.superteachertools.net
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2017-06-12T02:37:24.846Z <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp

By submitting a query to the Amazon Registrar, Inc. WHOIS database, you agree to abide by the following terms. The data in Amazon Registrar, Inc.'s WHOIS database is provided by Amazon Registrar, Inc. for the sole purpose of assisting you in obtaining information about domain name accuracy. You agree to use this data only for lawful purposes and further agree not to use this data for any unlawful purpose or to: (1) enable, allow, or otherwise support the transmission by email, telephone, or facsimile of commercial advertising or unsolicited bulk email, or (2) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes to collect or compile this data for any purpose, including mining this data for your own personal or commercial purposes. Amazon Registrar, Inc. reserves the right to restrict or terminate your access to the data if you fail to abide by these terms of use. Amazon Registrar, Inc. reserves the right to modify these terms at any time.

Visit Amazon Registrar, Inc. at https://registrar.amazon.com
Contact us at registrar@amazon.com or +1.2062661000

© 2017, Amazon.com, Inc., or its affiliates
```

Comment: whois is not the correct tool to diagnose DNS problems

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the destination server is not responding

I did a number of analysis and realized that your nameservers were configured as

```
ns2.superteachertools.net.    72.167.47.201
ns1.superteachertools.net.    72.167.47.201
```

Unforturnately, the server at 72.167.47.201 is offline

```
ping 72.167.47.201
PING 72.167.47.201 (72.167.47.201) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 72.167.47.201 ping statistics ---
175 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 173999ms
```

You will have to change the glue records to reflect the new server

Comment: Why do you think pinging a server has anything to do with its ability to respond to DNS queries?